# Java : Convert string to Date

Tags: java, parsing, date-formatting

i try to convert string to date , but when after the conversion the month is set to jan , but in input the month is other example 'sep' . following is my code.

```
Date tempDate = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").parse("09/12/2014");
System.out.println("Current Date " +tempDate);
```

output :

```
Current Date Sun Jan 12 00:09:00 IST 2014
```

Comment: This comes up every week, using the wrong format string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it is MM/dd/yyyy. not mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 8):

Reference these formats [Java Date Format Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

[image: Formats for datetime]

so `mm` is to reference minutes in hour while `MM` is for Month.

That is the reason you are getting:

`Current Date Sun Jan 12 00:09:00 IST 2014` from `("09/12/2014")`

by default month is `Jan` while it set minutes to '09' due to `mm`.

Comment: +1, all future questions like this should be linked this answer. you should include a reference to the javadoc though.